# Is there a command to turn the display off in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, display

When my Ubuntu machine is idle for a set period of time, the screen shuts off.

Is there a way to do that immediately using the terminal?

I'm guessing that it involves sending some sort of command to the x server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
xset dpms force off
```

should turn the screen off.

Comment: How to turn in on later then?